# Youtube Data API v3 inactivity email from Google

Tags: android, ios, youtube, youtube-data-api

In our app (both iOS and Android) we are playing some Youtube videos through the [Youtube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) flow and we do it by assigned the specific URL we need and initialise the player with a developer key assigned from Google Developer console which is indeed found under Youtube Data API v3 section.

We recently (2 weeks ago) got an email from Youtube stating that:

> Dear YouTube API Developer,
>
> According to our records, your project has been inactive for the past 90 consecutive days. In accordance with the YouTube API Services Developer Policies (link), we disabled your project’s access to and use of the YouTube Data API Service.
>
> This will not affect other Google API Services that you may have enabled on this project.
>
> For reference, your inactive project number is XXXXXXXX

We are frankly do not use any Data API v3 calls from anywhere in our app but we do use the developer key for initializing the player.

My question is if disabling our project for the Youtube Data API will also block our ability to play videos with this key?
Currently all works OK but we fear someday it just won't.

Any reference or advise for support from Youtube will be more than welcome.

Comment: did you find any answer elsewhere?

Comment: No, not yet. But videos still seems to load as usual with no further action.